Prove $\sum_{j=0}^{N} {N\brack j} \frac{z^{j}q^{j^{2}}}{(1-zq)(1-zq^{2})\cdot\cdot\cdot(1-zq^{j})}=\prod_{n=0}^{N} \frac{1}{1-zq^{n}}$
I am attempting exercise 101 from Integer Partitions by Andrews and Eriksson. That is, I want to prove

$\sum_{j=0}^{N} {N\brack j} \frac{z^{j}q^{j^{2}}}{(1-zq)(1-zq^{2})\cdot\cdot\cdot(1-zq^{j})}=\prod_{n=0}^{N} \frac{1}{1-zq^{n}}$

I know the right hand side is the generating function for the partitions of parts $\leq N$. I’m trying to use the Durfee square to show that the left hand side is also said generating function. I have thought of the following:
A partition of $N$ decomposes into a Durfee square of side $j$, a partition $\alpha$ with at most $j$ parts and a partition $\beta$ with parts at most $j$. The Durfee square is generated by $z^{j}q^{j^{2}}$, $\alpha$ is generated by ${N\brack j}$ and $\beta$ by $\prod_{i=0}^{j} \frac{1}{(1-zq^{i})}$. If we take their product and sum over $j$ to $N$ we get the generating function for partitions with parts at most $N$.
Is this correct? Any help is appreciated.

You are correct. Depending on your audience, you might need to go into more detail about why the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parts are as you say. Specifically, you might need to explain which of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is “on top” of the Durfee square, and which is “on the side”, and why each side gets a different formula.

Why does each side get a different formula? Suppose the Durfee square is a the top left of a Young diagram, is it because $\alpha$ is to the right of the square and $\beta$ below it. Such that $\alpha$ does not contribute anything to $z$?

I am going to take the time to set up some mathematical notation, in order to give you a fairly rigorous explanation. At the end of this question, I will try to give an intuitive explanation of the question in your comment. Let
$$
\newcommand{\len}{\operatorname{len}}
P(N)=\{\text{partitions where all parts are at most $N$}\}
\\
Q(N,j)=\{\text{partitions where all parts are at most $N-j$, with at most $j$ parts}\}
$$
These combinatorial sets have generating functions which you already know.
$$
\sum_{\lambda\in P(N)}z^{\len \lambda}q^{|\lambda|}=\prod_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{1-zq^i}.
\\
\sum_{\lambda\in Q(N,j)}q^{|\lambda|}={N\brack j}.
$$
Let us define a little more terminology.

Let $+$ denote the operation on partitions defined  as follows. If $\lambda_i=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots)$ and $\mu_i=(\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots)$, then $(\lambda+\mu)_i=(\lambda_1+\mu_1,\lambda_2+\mu_2,\dots)$. That is, we "stack $\lambda$ and $\mu$ on top of each other".
Let $\cup$ denote the operation on partitions defined as follows. Thinking of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ as multisets of numbers, simply combine the two multisets. So, $(6,4,3,1)\cup (5,1,1)=(6,5,4,3,1,1,1)$.
Let $j^j$ denote the square partition, with $j$ parts of size $j$.

Using the Durfee square construction, we can show that every $\lambda\in P(N)$ can be uniquely written in the form
$$
\lambda=\big(\alpha+j^j\big)\cup \beta ,
$$
for some positive integer $j$, and for some $\alpha\in Q(N,j)$, and for some $\beta\in P(j)$. With all of this background, we now have the power to prove your equation.
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{1-zq^i}
  &= \sum_{\lambda\in P(N)}z^{\len \lambda}q^{|\lambda|}
\\&\stackrel1= 
\sum_{j=1}^N 
\sum_{\alpha\in Q(N,j)}\sum_{\beta\in P(j)} 
z^{\len\big((\alpha+j^j)\cup \beta\big)}q^{|(\alpha+j^j)\cup \beta|}
\\&\stackrel2= 
\sum_{j=1}^N \sum_{\alpha\in Q(N,j)}\sum_{\beta\in P(j)} z^{j + \len(\beta)}q^{|\alpha|+j^2+|\beta|}
\\&= \sum_{j=1}^N z^{j}q^{j^2}\sum_{\alpha\in Q(N,j)}\sum_{\beta\in P(j)} q^{|\alpha|}z^{\len(\beta)}q^{|\beta|}
\\&= \sum_{j=1}^N z^{j}q^{j^2}
\left(\sum_{\alpha\in Q(N,j)}q^{|\alpha|}\right)
\left(\sum_{\beta\in P(j)} z^{\len(\beta)}q^{|\beta|}\right)
\\&= \sum_{j=1}^N z^{j}q^{j^2}{N\brack j}\prod_{i=1}^j\frac1{1-zq^i}
\end{align}
$$
Explanations:

This part follows from the Durfee square construction; summing over $\lambda$ is the same as summing over all possible $j,\alpha,\beta$.

Here is where the asymmetry between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ comes into play. Since $\alpha$ is stacked on top of the square, the number of parts of $\alpha$ does not contribute to the number of parts of $\lambda$, but $\beta$ is "horizontally" added to $j^j$, so $\beta$ does contribute. Hence, $\len(\lambda)=\len(j^j)+\len(\beta)=j+\len(\beta)$. However, $|\lambda|$ gets contributes from all of $\alpha,\beta$, and $j^j$.


